# Ipv6 route with Global Unicast Address

Tags: linux, networking, routing, virtualization, ipv6

### tl;dr

`ip -6 route replace 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe/128 via fd00:5151::1` gave me the error:

```
Error: Gateway can not be a local address.
```

Why is it not allowed to have a local address as gateway in a route? And how to fix the problem so that `2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe` reached via `fd00:5151::1`?

---

### Text

I want to assign a static Global Unicast IPv6 Address to a single VM.
The VM has `fd:5151::1` as it's gateway. My ISP gave me: `2001:db8:123:456::/64` Now the static IP should be: `2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe`.

The host should now redirect all incomming packages for that IP directly to the VM.
If I try to ping the Ip from the host with the command
everything works fine.

```
$ ping 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe

64 bytes from 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.453 ms
```

The VM also has the Ip assigned in `ip addr`.

```
inet6 fd00:5151::d8c:7603/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
   valid_lft 84146sec preferred_lft 84146sec
inet6 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe/128 scope global
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But If I try to ping the IP from a client e.g. a Windows PC. The connection fails.

```
ping 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe
Destination Port Unreachable
```

The host receives the incomming ping from the Windows PC on the interface `eno1` correctly. I checked this with `tcpdump -i eno1 host 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe`. But it doesn't redirect it.

To fix that I tried to use `ip -6 route replace 2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe/128 via fd00:5151::1` But Linux gave me the error:

```
Error: Gateway can not be a local address.
```

And now I don't understand why it is not allowed to have a local address as gateway in a route? And how to fix the problem so that the VM can be reached from the internet?

Comment: Sounds like you actually want *proxy_ndp*.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the virtualization software and the fact that the network is on the same machine the issue was caused.

I needed to set the Entry into the VM's network and everything worked.

```
<ip family='ipv6' address='2001:db8:123:456:fff:dead:beef:cafe' prefix='128'></ip>
```